# Multiple Search Form in one Submit button PHP/HTML

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to create a search query where in the user could either search the database using the firstname or lastname or both. I am able to do this using 1 type of search only, but if I do both I'm not sure how I could do this.

```
    <html>
  <head>
    <meta  http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;  charset=iso-8859-1">
    <title>Search  Contacts</title>
    <link href="site.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
  <body>

    <nav id="nav01"></nav>

    <div id="main">
    <h3>Search  Contact Details</h3>
    <form  method="post" action="#"  id="searchform">
      First Name:<br>
      <input  type="text" name="fname">
      <br>Last Name:<br>
      <input type="text" name="lname">
      <br>
      <input  type="submit" name="submit" value="Search">
    </form>

<?php
$servername = "xxx";
$username = "xxx";
$password = "xxx";
$dbname = "xxx";
$myquery = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST["fname"]);
$myquery2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['lname']);

// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}
// SQL query
if (!empty($myquery)) {

    $sql = "select distinct ID, FirstName, LastName, Email, PhoneNumber
           from Userlist where FirstName LIKE '%". $myquery  ."%' OR LastName LIKE '%".$myquery2."%'";

    //Get query on the database
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

    //Check results
    if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
    {
    //Headers
     echo "<table>";
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<th>Image ID</th>";
        echo "<th>Lastname</th>";
        echo "<th>Firstname</th>";
        echo "<th>Email</th>";
        echo "<th>PhoneNumber</th>";
        echo "</tr>";

  //output data of each row
      while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
        {
                echo "<tr>";
                  echo "<td>".$row['ID']."</td>";
                  echo "<td>".$row['LastName']."</td>";
                  echo "<td>".$row['FirstName']."</td>";
                  echo "<td>".$row['Email']."</td>";
                  echo "<td>".$row['PhoneNumber']."</td>";
                echo "</tr>";
        }
              echo "</table>";
    } else {
        echo "0 results";
    }
}

        mysqli_close($conn);

?>
<footer id="foot01"></footer>
</div>

<script src="script.js"></script>
</body>


</html>
```

Comment: What is desired behavior when both fields are specified in search? Do they both need to be fulfilled?

Comment: No they dont need to be both fulfilled but, if the user wants to be more specific he could fill out both and it would show the very exact row which has his/her entered firstname and lastname

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use OR and distinct on ID, so that you only get 1 entry if the user searchs for both, FirstName and LastName

```
$myquery = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST["fname"]); //<<< change $connection to your connection variable
$myquery2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['lname']);

$sql = "select distinct ID, FirstName, LastName, Email, PhoneNumber
           from Userlist where FirstName LIKE '%". $myquery  ."%' OR LastName LIKE '%".$myquery2."%'";
```

You should escape everything you search for in your query, either with

```
mysqli_real_escape_string
```

as written above, or you better use a [prepared statement](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php)

**EDIT:**

This :

```
$myquery = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST["fname"]);
$myquery2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($connection,$_POST['lname']);
```

needs to be after you established your connection. And as you are using $conn for your connection, you need to change it to

```
$myquery = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST["fname"]);
$myquery2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['lname']);
```

Like this:

```
<?php
$servername = "xxx";
$username = "xxx";
$password = "xxx";
$dbname = "xxx";


// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
$myquery = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST["fname"]);
$myquery2 = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn,$_POST['lname']);
```

Comment: Of course you should escape those values before using in a query.

Comment: I guess what the OP really wants is to search for a combination of first AND last name, if both are given. e.g. SQL `AND`

Comment: Good point, not so sure about this, but I'll change regarding to what OP answers on the comment @Kaii

Comment: Hi, thank you for this, I can't seem to search using lastname

Comment: How is your LastName column named in DB?

Comment: It is named as LastName as well

Comment: Should work, do you have anything else in your file? @XanderVane

Comment: I cant seem to search on both when i added the real escape code

Comment: Have you changed the $connection variable to your actual connection variable? @XanderVane

Comment: Hi i have edited my script and posted the whole one now

Comment: I've made an edit, please try it like this @XanderVane

Comment: I am able to search only on firstname but it shows all of my the records on my database

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```
<?php

      if(strlen($_POST["fname"])>0 AND strlen($_POST["lname"])>0){
            $sql = "SELECT ID, FirstName, LastName, Email, PhoneNumber FROM Userlist WHERE FirstName LIKE '%". $_POST["fname"])>."%' AND LastName LIKE '%". $_POST["lname"])>."%'";
      }
      elseif(strlen($_POST["fname"])>0 AND strlen($_POST["lname"])==0){
           $sql = "SELECT ID, FirstName, LastName, Email, PhoneNumber FROM Userlist WHERE FirstName LIKE '%". $_POST["fname"])>."%'";
      }
      elseif(strlen($_POST["lname"])>0 AND strlen($_POST["fname"])==0){
           $sql = "SELECT ID, FirstName, LastName, Email, PhoneNumber FROM Userlist WHERE LastName LIKE '%". $_POST["lname"])>."%'";
      }
      else{
          //No keywords specified
      }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Your code is subject to be sql injection attack  and so i have tried to make it better with corrections.**

```
<h3>Search  Contact Details</h3>
<form  method="post" action="#"  id="searchform">
  First Name:<br>
  <input  type="text" name="fname">
  <br>Last Name:<br>
  <input type="text" name="lname">
  <br>
  <input  type="submit" name="submit" value="Search">
</form>

<?php
/*USE PDO prepared statement to prevent mysql injection attacks*/
//PDo constructor instantiating instance of database object.
$pdo =  PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=YourDatabaseName;charset=utf8', 'YourUserName', 'YourPassword');
//check if something is submitted
if(isset($_POST['submit']) ){

//remove tags from the user input
$fname  = strip_tags('%'.$_POST['fname'].'%');
$lname   = strip_tags('%'.$_POST['lname'] .'%');    

//you need to use the if- conditional to 
//check if one or both fields are set 

if  ( (isset($fname) && !empty($fname)) || (isset($lname) && !empty($lname)) ) {

    try{
        $sql = "SELECT distinct ID, FirstName, LastName, Email, PhoneNumber
                 FROM Userlist
                 WHERE `FirstName` LIKE :FirstName  OR `LastName` LIKE :LastName";

         //Prepare the statment
        $query = $pdo->prepare($sql);
        $query->bindParam(':FirstName', $fname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->bindParam(':LastName', $lname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->execute();

        $result = $query->fetchAll();


    } catch (Exception $e) {
        print "Database Problem: " . $e->getMessage();
    }


}
//you can use foreach to display the result. 
    foreach ($result as $res): 
            echo $rs['FirstName']; //and so on
    endforeach;

}
else{
    echo 'search for some thing';

}

?>
```